# Unable to resolve filesystem provider with relative filepath opening file in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, uri, relative-path, vscode-extensions, absolute-path

I try to open a document in a VSCode extension using

```
vscode.window.showTextDocument(uri, options);
```

The uri looks like this

```
file:///c:/c2k/176141_Muster_V2.22.03/harddisk0/workspace/_global.tt/ercdata/ttc.properties
```

[image: Uri in the debug console]

The file **c:\c2k\176141_Muster_V2.22.03\harddisk0\workspace_global.tt\ercdata\ttc.properties** exists on drive c:, if I copy the whole path to the exlporer, the file opens.

Trying to open this file I get the following error:

**Error: Unable to resolve filesystem provider with relative file path**

which I didn't understand. The path is absolute, not relative. Does VSCode expect only relative pathes with this command?

Here is the error from the developer console:

[image]

WHat's going wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: what if you use `vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', uri, showOptions)` it returns a `Thennable`

Comment: I tried this, getting the error ""Running the contributed command: 'vscode.open' failed." from the Thenable errorhandler.

Comment: what was the error message? The same as with `vscode.window.showTextDocument`?

Comment: How are you obtaining the `Uri`?

Comment: I am using vscode.Uri.file(path)